# Build PETSc matrix with ghost line?

Tags: matrix, ghost, petsc

I know PETSc allows its vectors to carry ghost values thanks to VecCreateGhost() or VecMPISetGhost()functions.
Does anyone know if there is similar functions to create a matrix with ghost lines ? 
Thanks,
Myriam

Answer (score 0):

It seems that no such functions exist. So I have to change my matrices into vectors. The matrix object should be used only to build a linear system, not to store data.